# Prerequisites to start reading the "The Quantum Theory of Fields, Volume 1: Foundations " by Steven Weinberg

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education

As the title mentions, what are the prerequisites to reading  "The Quantum Theory of Fields, Volume 1: Foundations " by Steven Weinberg?

Comment: If you're starting to learn QFT and also asking this question, Weinberg is not for you. I think you should start studying QFT from either P&S, or Schwartz or Srednicki, get your hands wet with some calculations. IMHO one should only read Weinberg after already known a decent bit of QFT because it is vastly more useful then.

Comment: Solid courses on QM and classical field theory such as Weinberg's Lectures on Quantum Mechanics and Rubakov's Classical Theory of Gauge Fields. With that you will certainly be able to understand Weinberg's QFT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mandatory (up to some extent):

- Calculus
- Complex Analysis
- Differential Equations
- Special Relativity
- Quantum Mechanics

Optional:

- Differential Geometry

---

Personally, I found this book much more readable after reading:

- [Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/019969933X) by T. Lancaster
- [An Introduction To Quantum Field Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201503972) by M.E. Peskin & D.V. Schroeder

Reading [Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107034736) by M.D. Schwartz is highly advised too.